# IndentationError: unexpected indent on def parse_item(self, response) for scrapy,spider

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I am using scrapy to get some information from all pages of a website.
Here is my dmoz_spider.py file.when i execute this i get IndentationError.
Please help me out.

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
import string
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
class EypItem(Item):
    title = Field()
    link = Field()
    price = Field()
    review = Field()
class eypSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains =["http://www.walgreens.com"]
    start_urls =["http://www.walgreens.com/search/results.jsp?Ntt=allergy%20medicine"] 
rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('/search/results\.jsp', )), callback='parse_item', follow= True),)
    def parse_item(self, response):
    self.log('Hi, this is an item page! %s' % response.url)
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        sites = hxs.select('//div[@id="productGrid"]')
        items = []
        for site in sites:
            itemE = EypItem()
            itemE["title"] = site.select('//*[@class="image-container"]/a/img/@alt').extract()
            itemE["link"] = site.select('//*[@class="image-container"]/a/img/@src').extract()
            itemE["price"] = site.select('//*[@class="pricing"]/div/p/text()').extract()
            itemE["review"] = site.select('//*[@class="reviewSnippet"]/div/div/span/text()').extract()
            items.append(itemE)
        return items
```

Comment: Looks like the formatting got jumbled a bit here on stackoverflow, but try and put `def parse_item(self, response):` on the same indentation level as the line before it.

Comment: It looks like the line beginning `rules =` needed to be indented (and the `self.log` line indented one more level), assuming Ashwini's edit correctly represents your code.

Comment: Hi i tried with correct indentation still no luck..i removed the self.log, it is running but it is not crawling any data.getting this.Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the indentation error, your `allowed_domains` has been specified incorrectly. Change it as follows (which is to say, remove the "http://" prefix from the URL):

```
allowed_domains =["www.walgreens.com"]
```